# Optical lens for rotating a simple image

Tags: optics, lenses

I am asking if anyone could assist in my research on the development or procurement of a thin, economical, optical sheet/lens [ approx. size 300 mm square] that can rotate an image 90 degrees. I do not want to edit or modify the original image , but to rotate it 90 degrees. Image distance is small, less than 150 mm. As an example, consider a line of vertical text, I wish to rotate it 90 degrees to the horizontal when viewed through this lens.[possibly a multi layer, custom dove prism arrangement ?] Are you aware of any manufacturer of this type of product or potential leads for me to pursue? Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.
Best regards L S  , Engineer , Ottawa , Canada

Comment: As opposed to simply rotating the sensor or film ?  Or rotating the image captured if it's digital ?

Answer (score 1):

Two Dove prisms can do it. With 150 mm, you should be able to fit two Dove prisms in there. Each Dove prism performs an inversion of the image. Two inversions with a relative angle gives a rotation. So if the second Dove prism is rotated with an angle of $\phi$ around the optical axis relative to the first Dove prism, the image will be rotated by $2\phi$.

Answer (score 0):

Thin, economical - probably not.

You might try a fiber optic cable. That is a bundle of then optical fibers. Each one corresponds to a pixel.

There are some clever pairs of prisms. One sits on top of helicopter blades and spin with them. A rotating image is sent down the axis of the blades. The other is fixed. The image comes out in a fixed orientation.

One place to look is companies that make and sell optical components. If you have money to spend, they have engineers to talk to. The [RP Photonics Buyer's](https://www.rp-photonics.com/buyersguide.html) Guide can help you find companies. The and [RP Photonics Encyclopedia](https://www.rp-photonics.com/encyclopedia.html) can help you research optical components.